# Xamarin.Forms BluetoothPrinting

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

how can i print a pdf file using bluetooth printer as i have done something by using OCPP.PrinterThermal.Bluetooth but it is unable to print a pdf formatted file so can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i print using bluetoothservice then the file is in metadata format??

Comment: Can anyone please help me??